# How to display error message with php after form submit

Tags: php

Hello everyone i am building a project with php where do i want to display error message on form submit with php but the problem is i am unable to do that my page gets reloads and the message doesnot shows. Below i am pasting the codes please help me how to do that.

Form part

```
<form method="post" action="" id="contact_form">
                      <div class="form-row mt-3">
                        <div class="col">
                          <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="con_first_name" placeholder="Enter your first name">
                            <span><?php echo $err_fname; ?></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="form-group"> 
                      
                        <button type="submit" name="con_submit" class="btn show_more con_submit">Submit</button>
                      </div> 
                    </form>
```

php codes

```
if(isset($_POST['con_submit'])){
    
    
    
    // Posted form data 
    
    if(!empty($_POST['con_first_name'])){
        $err_fname = "First name cannot be empty";
    }else{
        $fname = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['con_first_name'])), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `!empty()` is the validation you want, rather than `empty()` without the `!`?

Comment: @rickdenhaan do you think `empty()` will work

Comment: Well, you want to set the error message when the user has NOT entered a first name, correct? So when the field *is* `empty()`

Comment: Yes @rickdenhaan

Comment: Then using `empty()` should work. A quick test would be to set `$err_fname` in your `else` condition as well (to some other text) to see if it displays then.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use with session like this

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['con_submit'])){
    
    // Posted form data 
    if(empty($_POST['con_first_name'])){
        $err_fname = "First name cannot be empty";
        $_SESSION['form_error_name'] = $err_fname;
    }else{
        $fname = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['con_first_name'])), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
     
}

if(isset($_SESSION['form_error_name'])){
    echo $_SESSION['form_error_name'];
    unset($_SESSION['form_error_name']);
}
```

session is secure and every time you post it will set session and then it will remove the value set is session with unset the session.

Comment: Nope! see the difference in `empty`

Comment: you could comment on my answer about my mistace not copy my solution. ..

Comment: Ok I got that @Ingus

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with session!

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['con_submit'])){
    
    // Posted form data 
    if(!empty($_POST['con_first_name'])){
        $err_fname = "First name cannot be empty";
        $_SESSION['form_error'] = $err_fname;
    }else{
        $fname = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['con_first_name'])), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
     
}
```

And then where you want to show it do:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['form_error'])){
    echo $_SESSION['form_error'];
    unset($_SESSION['form_error']);
}
```

Comment: is using session is safe and why unset

Comment: @BabyBabai Yes it is safe! Unset to hide message if page is refreshed. .. once showed it does not need to be showed again!

Comment: The condition should say `if (empty())` instead of `if (!empty())`

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
if(isset($_POST['con_submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['con_first_name'])){
        $err_fname = "First name cannot be empty";
    }else{
        $fname = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['con_first_name'])), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```